# PHP function pdf_open

Tags: php, pdf

I copied php's sources from a Debian server to a windows environment (with wamp). There is a couple of calls to `pdf_open` a function which isn't declare anywhere, even not in an included library. 
I'd like to make this code work on my environment but Google searches didn't get me any answer.
Maybe it is a PHP version issue since the Debian runs PHP 4 and I have PHP 5.3 on local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a php native function but it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php), use `pdf_new()` and `pdf_open_file()` instead.

Comment: is there any extension or module to activate or install to make it work ?

Comment: Use `function_exists` and if not, define it.